# Why does adding a style or reference inside a parsed-literal break the theme of the block?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

When using parsed-literal, why does adding a style or reference break the theme?
For example with the `sphinx_rtd_theme` a parsed literal block has a green background. But If I add any style inside the parsed-literal block the background becomes white. How do I keep the theme, even when I have styles or references inside it?

This works fine and give green background

```
.. parsed-literal::

   test
```

This background becomes white

```
.. parsed-literal::

   test
   **test**
```

I have tried to google for alternatives to parse-literal, but can find any options.

Comment: Seems related to https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2167

Comment: To get syntax highlighting for code, use `code-block`. To render inline markup in a literal block, use `parsed-literal`. AFAICT, it is not (currently) possible to have both these features at the same time.

Comment: Okay. It would be nice to have code blocks where I can click on each function and get to that function documentation. But I guess that is not possible then.